# Open all files in different directory python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to open a file from a different directory without using it's path while staying in the current directory.

When I execute the below code:

```
for file in os.listdir(sub_dir):
    f = open(file, "r")
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line.replace("dst=", ", ")
        line.replace("proto=", ", ")
        line.replace("dpt=", ", ")
```

I get the error message `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:` because it's in a sub directory.

**Question**: Is there an os command I can use that will locate and open the file in `sub_dir`?

Thanks! -let me know if this is a repeat, I searched and couldn't find one but may have missed it.

Comment: you need to add the sub_dir path to your file in the open() function to be able to open it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`os.listdir()` lists *only* the filename without a path. Prepend these with `sub_dir` again:

```
for filename in os.listdir(sub_dir):
    f = open(os.path.join(sub_dir, filename), "r")
```

If all you are doing is loop over the lines from the file, just loop over the file itself; using `with` makes sure that the file is closed for you when done too. Last but not least, `str.replace()` **returns** the new string value, not change the value itself, so you need to store that return value:

```
for filename in os.listdir(sub_dir):
    with open(os.path.join(sub_dir, filename), "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.replace("dst=", ", ")
            line = line.replace("proto=", ", ")
            line = line.replace("dpt=", ", ")
```

Comment: If I wanted to write the new line to `filename`, would I add `f.write(line)` and open in `a` mode?

Comment: @hjames: Sure, just adjust the `mode` parameter of the `open()` call.

Comment: Hmm, if I put it in `a` or `w` mode, it returns an error that the file isn't readable. If I put it in `r` mode it obviously can't write to the file.

Comment: `io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable` or `io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable`

Comment: @hjames: Do you need to open the file for *both* reading and writing? Then use `r+` or `w+` (open existing file, `r` will leave existing data there, `w` will truncate existing files).

Answer (score 11):

You must give the full path if those files are not in the current directory:

```
f = open( os.path.join(sub_dir, file) )
```

I would not use `file` as a variable name, maybe `filename`, since this is used to create a file object in Python.

Answer (score -1):

Code to copy files using shutil

```
import shutil
import os

source_dir = "D:\\StackOverFlow\\datasets"
dest_dir = "D:\\StackOverFlow\\test_datasets"
files = os.listdir("D:\\StackOverFlow\\datasets")

if not os.path.exists(dest_dir):
    os.makedirs(dest_dir)

for filename in files:
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        shutil.copy(os.path.join(source_dir, filename), dest_dir)

print os.listdir(dest_dir)
```